# How to keep a modal open when submitting php script

Tags: javascript, php

Hi all im trying to to run a php quote calculator from within a bootstap modal, the php runs fine but as its server side as soon as the page refreshes the model closes, if i open the modal again the result is displayed. I would really appreciate some assistance!

Im new to this and have read that running the code through ajax may solve the issue but i have no idea how to do this.

Would it be better to have a separate page for the php or is it ok combined.?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',0);
if( isset( $_REQUEST['calculate'] )){
$size=$_REQUEST['size'];
$quan = (int)$_REQUEST['quantity']; // Casts the value to Integer
if($size=="A3"){
$res= $quan * 1.2;
}

if($size=="A2"){
$res= $quan * 1.8;
}

if($size=="A1"){
$res= $quan * 2.5;
}

if($size=="A0"){
$res= $quan * 3.2;
}

if($_REQUEST['quantity']==NULL)
{
echo "<script language=javascript> alert(\"Please Enter values.\");</script>";
}
else if($_REQUEST['quantity']==NULL)
{
echo "<script language=javascript> alert(\"Please Enter Quantity.\");</script>";}

}
?>
<div class="poster-modal">
<!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#posterModal" class="button"></a>
<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="posterModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Poster Quote</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form>
<tr>
<td>Quantity<input name="quantity" type="text" size="5" /></td>
</tr>
<br>
<br>
<tr>
<td>Size<select name="size">
<option selected="selected">A3</option>
<option>A2</option>
<option>A1</option>
<option>A0</option>
</select></td>
</tr>  
<br>
<br>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<td><input type="Submit" name="calculate" value="calculate"></td>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<td style="text-align:right;">Price</td>
<td class="feedback" style="font-weight:bolder;font-size:20px;color:#F00;"><?php echo $res;?></td>
</tr>
</div>
</td>                   
</form>
</div>
</div>                  
</div>
</div>
```

I would also like the end result to display the completed fields, And have a clear or refresh button.

i.e. 100 A3 Poster is $20.

Comment: "i have no idea how to do this." ...you can find a million and one AJAX tutorials online. I suggest starting there. Try something, if you get stuck then ask us a specific question about your error/problem. Hint: the modern way to do it is using the [Fetch API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch). Avoid tutorials which use XMLHttpRequest or require jQuery etc, it shouldn't be necessary (unless you need to support old browsers)

Comment: Also read up on how to prevent default form submit with javascript

Comment: Thanks ive looked into it - will keep at it :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to keep windows from closing when the page refreshes. It's as if you switched your computer off. You should indeed take a little time to learn about ajax. Ajax calls PHP pages, sends parameters for processing data and returns results without refreshing. It's the next level:)

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for the reply - on it